# Searching XML using XPath for multiple values for Search Result page

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to search XML using XPath code:

```
$results = $xml->xpath("Property/Floorplan[SquareFeet / @Min>='".$minarea."' or EffectiveRent / @Min>='".$minprice."' or Room[@RoomType='Bathroom'] / Count>='".$minbath."' or Room[@RoomType='Bedroom'] / Count>='".$minbeds."']/parent::*");
```

It is not working as desired. What I am looking for is, it should look into XML for Minimum Values set in Variables in SquareFeet, EffectiveRent, Room > Bedroom and Bathroom.
For example:

- $minarea= 2000,
- $minprice = 500,
- $minbath = 2,
- $minbeds = 2.

Code currently returning all nodes without matching.
Also, I want to add more functionality to search for city, state and zip.

Here is my XML code:

```
<PhysicalProperty xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Property>
        <PropertyID>
            <Address AddressType="property">
                <Address>518 Cedar St</Address>
                <City>Monticello</City>
                <State>MN</State>
                <PostalCode>55362</PostalCode>
            </Address>
        </PropertyID>
        <Floorplan>
            <Room RoomType="Bedroom">
                <Count>0</Count>
            </Room>
            <Room RoomType="Bathroom">
                <Count>0</Count>
            </Room>
            <SquareFeet Min="1680" Max="1680"/>
            <MarketRent Min="0" Max="0"/>
            <EffectiveRent Min="1295" Max="1295"/>
        </Floorplan>
    </Property>
</PhysicalProperty>
```

This is the complete PHP code:

```
$all_active = get_template_directory().'/propertxml/propertyall.xml';
$xml=simplexml_load_file($all_active);
$results = $xml->xpath("Property/Floorplan[SquareFeet / @Min>=".$minarea." and EffectiveRent / @Min>=".$minprice." and Room[@RoomType='Bathroom'] / Count>=".$minbath." and Room[@RoomType='Bedroom'] / Count>=".$minbeds."]/parent::*"); 
if(!empty($results))
{
foreach($results as $res7){

$tt = $res7->PropertyID[0]->MarketingName;
$desc=$res7->Information->LongDescription;
$rent = $res7->Floorplan->EffectiveRent->attributes()->Min;
$area=$res7->Floorplan->SquareFeet->attributes()->Min ;
$bed=$res7->Floorplan->Room[0]->Count;
$bath = $res7->Floorplan->Room[1]->Count;
$url = $res7->Floorplan->FloorplanAvailabilityURL; 
$address = $res7->PropertyID[0]->Address->Address;
$unitcount = $res7->Information->UnitCount;
$rent = $res7->Floorplan->EffectiveRent->attributes()->Min;
$ptype=$res7->ILS_Identification->attributes()->ILS_IdentificationType; }
```

Comment: Please show a complete PHP script which can be used to reproduce your problem and also show clearly what you want the output of the program to look like. Thanks.

Comment: I have added PHP code, thanks.

Comment: I just want PHP script to search XML file for City, State and Zip and then I will be showing all Properties matching that City, State, Zip, Min. Beds, Min. Baths, Min. Rent. which it got from search Form's fields through GET. My script works for Min. Bed Bath but I dont know how to add City/State and Zip into it.